# How to access Django Model Fields from save_formset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-modeladmin

I have an Inline Model in Django model admin , and I need to create a condition before saving the items, here is the code am using :

```py
class PRCItemInline(admin.TabularInline):


    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(PRCItemInline, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['product'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'width: 50px;'
        return form

    ordering = ['id']
    model = PRCItem
    extra = 1
    autocomplete_fields = [
        'product',
        'supplier',
    ]

    fields = (
        'product',  # 1
        'quantity',  # 2
        'unitary_value_reais_updated',  # 4
        'issuing_status',
        'approval_status',
        'receiving_status',
    )
    readonly_fields = ['issuing_status',
                       'approval_status',
                       'receiving_status',
                       ]

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        obj = form.instance
        if obj.purchase_request.is_analizer:
            return HttpResponse("You can't change this")
        else:
            obj.save()
```

As you see, I used the `save_formset` method to be able to reach the fields of the model, and then filter based on it. but it just saves the items no matter the If statement I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing:

List item `save_formset` should not return anything, the `HttpResponse` will not work for you.
Even if it would this is just not proper way. Not mentioning that it will not be very informational.

### 1st solution

`obj.purchase_request.is_analizer` should be done during form validation

Any `ValidationError` raised there will be propagated to the formset and displayed in error message next to relevant form.

```
class PRCItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def validate(self):
        if obj.purchase_request.is_analizer:
            raise ValidationError("You can't change this")
```

### 2nd solution

override `get_queryset()` and filter out the objects you cannot edit

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    return qs.exclude(purchase_request__is_analizer=True)
```